# What causes the thread to hang and doesn't throw anything even after 20 hours

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0

I have threads inside thread and the last sub-thread just hangs and doesn't throw anything for 20 hrs now. My code was something like this:

```
bool end = false;

var t1 = new Thread(() =>
{
    // ...

    var t2 = new Thread(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            foreach(Data data in datas2)
            {
                foreach(SubData subdata in data.SubDatas)
                {
                    var t3 = new Thread(() =>
                    {
                        this.SaveData(subdata.RetrieveData());
                    }); t3.Start();

                    if (!t3.Join(1800000))
                    {
                        t3.Abort();
                        throw new TimeoutException("The execution of method is taking too long.");
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch { throw; }
        finally { end = true; }
    }); t2.Start();
}); t1.Start();
```

It never goes through the `finally` block of `t2` and it doesn't throw any error. What is happening here?

My code is in C#, framework 4, build in Visual Studio 2010 Pro.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

---

**Edit:**
Thanks everyone for your help. I have found the answer and it is

> **an infinite loop.**

Our production stopped for a week for this stupid bug. Ugh. It seems like there has a validation on our system that creates an infinite loop for some data only. Thanks everyone for being enthusiastic in solving this question.

Comment: Does `t3` finish execution? When do you use the `end` variable?

Comment: depends what happens in SaveData and RetrieveData

Comment: @YoryeNathan `t3` doesn't finish execution. I have another thread that check if the `t2` has ended. The `end` was actually a class variable with the type `private volatile bool`.

Comment: @KeithNicholas If `SaveData` or `RetrieveData` is taking too long (over 30 minutes), the `t3.Abort()` should have executed and throws a `TimeoutException`.

Comment: @JohnIsaiahCarmona  But abort isn't guaranteed to terminate the thread, as per my answer

Comment: Round brackets unbalanced. What part of code you did not show in your example ?

Comment: @RocketSurgeon That was just actually a pseudo-code. My real code was too complex and lengthy. Sorry, I'll edit it.

Comment: Looks like a good candidate for the Tasks Parallel Library (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this the problem in your case....

However, Thread.Abort raises an exception  ( a special one, that even if you catch it, once the catch and finally have finished it will auto rethrow itself unless you clear the abort ).   If the code in SaveData and RetriveData catch the exception and then either in the catch or finally end up being blocked, it won't abort.

Comment: What do you mean by _either in the catch or finally end up being blocked_? What and how is it being blocked?

Comment: if its waiting for something? locked against something else? Invoking something on another thread, or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably something going on in SaveData or RetrieveData that we don't know about.  It is possible that you could be doing extremely long/repetetive I/O that we don't know about.

Additionally, I don't think that this code is doing what you think it is doing.  See my //NOTE: below:

```
            foreach(SubData subdata in data1.SubDatas)
            {
                var t3 = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    this.SaveData(subdata.RetrieveData());
                }); t3.Start();

                // NOTE: Here you are blocking each iteration of T2 
                // while T3 runs.  There is no reason to be running 
                // another thread here- just call SaveData/RetrieveData 
                // from T2.  Additionally, because this is executing in 
                // a double-nested loop, you might be doing this many, 
                // many times.  I'd suggest looking into ThreadPool or TPL.

                if (!t3.Join(1800000))
                {
                    t3.Abort();
                    throw new TimeoutException("The execution of method is taking too long.");
                }
            }
```

Comment: I actually intended to block `t2` while `t3` is running, I just put it to another thread for adding a `TimeoutException` into it when it is taking too long to run. `RetrieveData` was a memory intensive process that connects to a WCF service.